# How to prevent: knitting to pdf converts hat symbol "^" -> "ˆ"

Tags: r-markdown

I have a code chunk that uses the hat symbol, e.g. `str_detect(c("word", "another_word"), "^word")`. When knitting the rmarkdown file to pdf and I copy the code back to the console it becomes `str_detect(c("word", "another_word"), "ˆword")`, .i.e. ^ -> ˆ. How can I prevent that?